# How to create a wind tunnel / sky diving effect like in Fortnite?

Tags: unity, particles

I am using Unity and I want to create a sky diving effect, as if you were looking directly down while falling and have the wind fly past you. My guess is I have to do something with the particle system. How can I do this?

[image: Screenshot from Fortnite showing pale streaks from character's hands & feet]

An example is this video of Fortnite https://youtu.be/JFHs3uNJ9Cw?t=23s, you can see the wind flowing from the characters hands and feet.

Comment: For "how can I create a ______ effect" questions, a visual target is extremely helpful. Do you have some images or example animations that demonstrate the style you want to achieve?

Comment: @DMGregory I updated my answer and added an example.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you can accomplish a similar effect by...

1. Attach an object with a TrailRenderer component to each point on the model that should send out streaks (eg. the hands & feet)
2. Set the material on the trails to use a wispy, cloudy texture, and pan it the texture down the trail over time to create a blowing/streaking effect.
3. Set the TrailRenderer's colours so that the trail fades to transparent by the end of the ribbon.

Make sure to test on an object in motion so you can see how the changes affect the trails. A stationary object won't leave trails behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of a Trail Renderer and Particles.
The particles should be set to world space and attached to the character to recreate a "trail effect". There is a plenty of tutorials on youtube on how to do good looking particles ! The trick here is really "world space" particles.